# Decrease the width of DatePicker in UWP XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

What is the right way to set the width on the DatePicker element?

I tried:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="birthDatePicker" Width="200" Header="Date of birth"/>
```

Which lead to the date picker button cutoff:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your issue, you could put the DatePicker inside [Viewbox control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox?view=winrt-20348) and set the MaxHeight and Maxwidth property of ViewBox to resolve this issue.

As follows:

```
<Viewbox MaxHeight="50" MaxWidth="100">
      <DatePicker x:Name="birthDatePicker1" /> 
</Viewbox>
```

**Update:**

You could set the `Stretch` property to `Fill`, then you could adjust the height and width of DatePicker according the MaxHeight and MaxWidth properties of Viewbox. As for the font size, you could change the `FontSize` property of DatePicker directly.

```
<Viewbox MaxHeight="40" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill">
            <DatePicker x:Name="birthDatePicker1" FontSize="20" />
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: This works. But, it scales down the entire element including font size and the height of the date picker.

Comment: @gunturumahesh I have updated my answer, please try it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit long, but this is the DatePicker template, I added a desired width in the grid I called "TheGridIChanged" in line 21.

add it to **<Page.Resources> </Page.Resources>**

and add to the DatePicker: **Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle1}"**

```
    <Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle1" TargetType="DatePicker">
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"> 
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="DatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="ElementSoundMode" Value="FocusOnly"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid x:Name="TheGridIChanged" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="100">
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBackgroundFocused}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonForegroundFocused}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Background="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource DatePickerButtonBorderBrush}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerHeaderForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FirstPickerSpacing" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerFillDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SecondPickerSpacing" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerFillDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HasDateStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="HasDate"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="HasNoDate">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="DayTextBlock.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}"/>
                                        <Setter Target="MonthTextBlock.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}"/>
                                        <Setter Target="YearTextBlock.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource DatePickerHeaderForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{ThemeResource DatePickerTopHeaderMargin}" MaxWidth="{ThemeResource DatePickerThemeMaxWidth}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" MinWidth="{StaticResource DatePickerThemeMinWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource DatePickerThemeMaxWidth}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="{TemplateBinding UseSystemFocusVisuals}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid x:Name="FlyoutButtonContentGrid">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DayColumn" Width="78*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="FirstSpacerColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MonthColumn" Width="132*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="SecondSpacerColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="YearColumn" Width="78*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="DayTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Padding="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterItemPadding}" Text="Day" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MonthTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterMonthPadding}" Text="Month" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="YearTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Padding="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterItemPadding}" Text="Year" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FirstPickerSpacing" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerFill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="2"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SecondPickerSpacing" Grid.Column="3" Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerSpacerFill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

To get to the template of an object, you can right-click on it (in Design) and select Edit Template:

[To get to the template of an object, you can right-click on it (in Design) and select Edit Template:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcYeS.png)